# How to handle whitespace in DataTrigger binding for WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I am using autogenerating datagrid and binding it to a DataTable.This DataTable has columns with whitespaces like 'Last Value'. Now I need to add a datatrigger to apply some style as shown below:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>                        
                    <Style x:Key="DgStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>                               
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Last Value, Converter= {StaticResource DecimalToBoolConverter}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

But DataTrigger Binding doesn't support whitespaces (Last Value). When I remove the whitespace(LastValue) then it works fine. But as per my requirement I need whitespace in the datatable columns name and this table is being used to bind datagrid.

How could I handle this scenario?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

You can use single quote on the property name.

```
Binding={Binding 'Last Value', Converter= {StaticResource DecimalToBoolConverter}}"
```

Comment: This is missing a double quote right after the equal sign.

Comment: Also, in VB.net WPF projects it will be Binding={Binding [Last Value]... So using [ ] as delimiters, not single quotes.