# WPF How to handle property names with spaces?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

A simple question with i had problems several times and i dind´t find a solution so far. For sure it is a peanut for you.

I am trying to bind the Text property of a comboBox to a column in the dataTable. If the column name has no spaces it is working:
For example:

```
Text="{Binding Path= MyColumn, ... }"
```

If the name has a space in between it doesn´t work:
For example:

```
Text="{Binding Path= My Column, ... }"
```

There must be something indicating the compiler that the name consists of both words with the space ("My Column"). But i didn´t find it yet.

Thanks

Comment: You are therefore punished for using a space in a table column. Have you tried to simply set an alias to the column name in your query ? `SELECT [My Column] AS MyColumn`

Comment: Have you tried using: &#x20; instead of the space?

Comment: yes, but normally you want to have it with the space as a Alias for the title of teh column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle whitespace in DataTrigger binding for WPF DataGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734954/how-to-handle-whitespace-in-datatrigger-binding-for-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following delimiters did not work: `"" [] {}`

What you need is single quotes `''`

```
Text="{Binding Path= 'My Column', ... }"
```

Comment: This is known as [Rubber duck problem solving](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)

Answer (score 1):

```
Text="{Binding Path= 'My Column', ... }"
```

didn't work for me so I tried the code below that worked fine.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="My Column"/>
    </TextBox.Text>  
</TextBox>
```